# git commit created locally. when pushing to remote, icannot push my local commit as the branch has updates waiting to be pulled

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have made some changes on my local branch and created commit locally. when i push my local commit to remote, it prevents push as i have two updates recently from the remote branch of it waiting to be pulled. how to save my work safely and prevent this conflict. other people also work parallel on the same branch

branch name: feature-1

Comment: Pull first or rename your branch. `feature-1` is a terrible name for a branch

Comment: if i pull first, will my locally commited changes be lost?

Comment: No, they will be merged

Comment: You should reeeeeeally consider going through some git guides. These are questions answered millions of times already on the internet.

Comment: hi @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED, i like myself be called a lazy coder

Comment: That's your problem then. Not ours.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked and answered millions of times on the internet before and OP has admitted not doing an iota of research prior to coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `git pull origin feature-1` This will pull latest changes and merge them with your code. If there are conflicts you will have to fix them and add/commit them. Then push your branch and all should be fine.